# Java Calendar Alignment Issues

Tags: java

I am trying to print a Calendar in Java based on the month and year provided.  I am able to get the program to print the proper number of days in the month and to print on the next line of the calendar after 7 days are up, but I cannot get it to offset in the case where the first of the month is not Sunday.  Also, the numbers for the dates should be neatly aligned, which I cannot get my code to produce either.  I am very certain that my issue is in the printMonthBody method.  Should I be using a switch here?  I have tried incorporating solutions that I have found online, but still have no luck.  Any and all suggestions are welcome!  Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calendar {

  public static void main(String [] args) 
  {    
    int m = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int startday;

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );     // Create a Scanner     to obtain user input

    System.out.print( "Enter the month (ex. 1 for January, 5 for May): " );
    m = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print( "Enter the year (ex. 2012, 2020): " );
    y = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    d = getNumDaysInMonth(m ,y);

    startday = getStartDay(m, y ,d);
    System.out.println( "\t"  + startday);  

    printMonthCalendar( m, d, y );
  }

  public static void printMonthCalendar( int m, int d, int y) 
  {
    printMonthHeader( m, y );
    printMonthBody( m, d, y );
  }

  public static void printMonthHeader( int m, int y) 
  { 
    System.out.println( "         " + getMonthName( m ) + " " + getYear( y ));
    System.out.println( "---------------------------" );
    System.out.println( "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
  }

  public static void printMonthBody( int m, int d, int y ) 
  {  
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        switch(i) {
            case 1: //Mon
            System.out.print( "  " + i);
            x++;
                if (x % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.println(); 
                }   
            break;
        case 2: //Tue
            {
            System.out.print( "     " + i);
            x++;
                if (x % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.println(); 
                }
            }
            break;
        case 3: //Wed
            {
            System.out.print( "         " + i);
            x++;
                if (x % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.println(); 
                }
            }
            break;
        case 4: //Thu
            {
            System.out.print( "             " + i);
            x++;
                if (x % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.println(); 
                }
            }
            break;
        case 5: //Fri
            {
            System.out.print( "                 " + i);
            x++;
                if (x % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.println(); 
                }
            }
            break;
        case 6: //Sat
            {
            System.out.print( "                    " + i);
            x++;
                if (x % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.println(); 
                }
            }
            break;
        case 7: //Sun
            {
            System.out.print( "                       " + i);
            x++;
                if (x % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.println(); 
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}    

  }


  //use an array to organize months with # of days in each month
  public static String getMonthName( int m ) 
  {
    String[] month = { " ", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",     "Jul", "Aug", 
        "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };
    return month[m];  
  }

    public static int getYear( int y ) 
  { //I added this method to get the year from user
        return y;
  }

  public static int getStartDay( int m, int d, int y )
  { // Adjust month number & year to fit Zeller's numbering system
    if ( m < 3 ) 
    {
    m = m + 12;
    y = y - 1;
    }

    int k = y % 100;      // Calculate year within century
    int j = y / 100;      // Calculate century term
    int h = 0;            // Day number of first day in month 'm'

    h = ( d + ( 13 * ( m + 1 ) / 5 ) + k + ( k / 4 ) + ( j / 4 ) + ( 5 * j ) ) % 7;

    // Convert Zeller's value to ISO value (1 = Mon, ... , 7 = Sun )
    int dayNum = ( ( h + 5 ) % 7 ) + 1;     

    return dayNum;
  }

  public static int getNumDaysInMonth( int m, int y ) 
  { 
    int[] numDays = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    //call is leap year method to calc num of days in feb
    if ( ( m == 2 ) && ( isLeapYear(y) == true ) ) 
           numDays[2] = 29;
    return numDays[m];               
  }

  public static boolean isLeapYear( int y ) 
  {
    if ( ( y % 4 == 0 ) && ( y % 100 != 0 ) && ( y % 400 == 0 ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
  }


}
```

Comment: Given the fact that you know the start day, you need to pre-pad your output with blank "entries" before you start printing the main body

Comment: Could you please show an example of what you mean by that?  I am in week 3 of my first programming class so this is all really new to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that you know the `startDay` of the month, you need to pre-pad the first line of output to offset the first of the month, for example...

```
public static void printMonthBody(int m, int d, int y) {
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;

    int startDay = -getStartDay(m, d, y);
    for (int date = startDay; date < d; date++) {
        if (date <= 0) {
            System.out.printf("%3s ", "");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%3d ", date);
        }

        x++;
        if (x % 7 == 0) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Which can print out something like...

```
         Mar 2016
---------------------------
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                      1   2 
  3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
 10  11  12  13  14  15  16 
 17  18  19  20  21  22  23 
 24  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

I highly, highly, highly recommend that you have a look at [Formatted Strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html), it will make the whole process much eaiser

Oh, I'm not going to debug your `getStartDay` method, but it's giving me erroneous results, March 2016 should start on a `Tuesday`.

Comment: Our professor hasn't gone over formatted strings yet, but I will definitely read about these after a good night's sleep!  As for the getStartDay method--you're right, it does print the first date the day after it should.  The start date according to the program is 5, which should be Thursday but it is actually Tuesday, but it prints the 1st on Friday...

Comment: One other question though: what does the minus symbol mean in this line?  int startDay = -getStartDay(m, d, y); I haven't seen this before.

Comment: The `String` formatting will save you a lot of code when trying to determine how many spaces you need to use to fill a "cell".  Yes, I played around with the values for the `getStartDay`, changing the parameters to see if I could get a correct result, but obviously...The `-getStartDay(m, d, y)` basically makes the the value negative (so a return value of `1` becomes `-1`). You may need to play around with that, as you know need to take into consideration `-n` to `0` as been "padding" days, which is (based on my thinking about it), likely to add an extra (pad) day (but you could just add 1)

Comment: Roger thank you, I am going to play around with this a bit and see if I can't get it to come out right.  I feel like I actually just learned something too!  I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Glad it could help give you some ideas ;)